# Using Multiple MCP23017 chip's - addressing problem

Tags: arduino

I am trying to use multiple mcp23017 chips in parallel, but not all the time I will use the same number of chips. My code is done for one address, the default one ... but for using multiple addresses it is required to declare another mcp instance, each one for all existing address ? Because in this way, if I am using 8 chip's, my code will be very very big ... I can use somehow a loop which search all addresses ( done ) and use only one mcp instance for all addresses ?

```c
/*
Name : Program for MCP23017 uC with Arduino Board
Version : v1_01
Date : 26.06.2019
Author : 

ALL RIGHTS RESERVED

NOTE : Install the Adafruit MCP23017 library
          1. Open the Arduino IDE
          2. Select 'Sketch' -> 'Include Library' -> 'Manage Libraries'
          3. Search for '23017'
          4. Click 'Install' button for the 'Adafruit MCP23017 Arduino Library...'
*/

// v1_02 - change commands handling
// v1_03 - add I2C Scanner 

#include "Wire.h"
#include "Adafruit_MCP23017.h"

Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp; // Create mcp0 instance : Chip 0

int dly = 250;

void setup() 
{

   Serial.begin(9600);
   Serial.println("Continental Timisoara - FF PSS ECC IE TE");
   Wire.begin();

 /// Scan I2C addresses

  byte error, address;
  int nDevices;

  Serial.println("Scanning...");

  nDevices = 0;
  for(address = 1; address < 127; address++ )
  {
    // The i2c_scanner uses the return value of
    // the Write.endTransmisstion to see if
    // a device did acknowledge to the address.
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    error = Wire.endTransmission();

    if (error == 0)
    {
      Serial.print("I2C device found at address 0x");
      if (address<16)
        Serial.print("0");
      Serial.print(address,HEX);
      Serial.print(address);
      Serial.println("  !");

      nDevices++;
    }
    else if (error==4)
    {
      Serial.print("Unknown error at address 0x");
      if (address<16)
        Serial.print("0");
      Serial.println(address,HEX);
    }    
  }
  if (nDevices == 0)
    Serial.println("No I2C devices found\n");
  else
    Serial.println("done\n");

 /// -------------------



   mcp.begin(0); // Start mcp on Hardware address 0x20 ( all pins LOW )

   for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) 
   {
    mcp.pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
   }

   for(int i = 8; i <= 15; i++) 
   {
    mcp.pinMode(i, INPUT);
   }

}

void loop() {

  if(Serial.available()>0)
  {
      String letter = "";

  while(Serial.available()>0)
  {
  letter +=char(Serial.read());
  delay(100);
  }

   // =========================================================================================

    String Command = "";
    Command = letter.substring(2,3);

    String Reset = "";
    Reset = letter.substring(1,4);

    if (Command == "A")
    {

     String sOutput_Port = "";
     sOutput_Port = letter.substring(4,5);
     int iOutput_Port = sOutput_Port.toInt();

     mcp.digitalWrite(iOutput_Port,HIGH);
     int iInput_Port = iOutput_Port + 8;
     if(mcp.digitalRead(iInput_Port)==HIGH)
        {
        String Show = "Channel ";
        Show.concat(sOutput_Port);
        Show.concat(" is ON");

        Serial.println(Show);        
        }
        else
        {
        Serial.println("NO VALIDATION"); 
        }

    }


  if (Command == "I")
    {

     String sOutput_Port = "";
     sOutput_Port = letter.substring(4,5);
     int iOutput_Port = sOutput_Port.toInt();


     mcp.digitalWrite(iOutput_Port,LOW);
     int iInput_Port = iOutput_Port + 8;
     if(mcp.digitalRead(iInput_Port)==LOW)
        {
        String Show = "Channel ";
        Show.concat(sOutput_Port);
        Show.concat(" is OFF");

        Serial.println(Show);        
        }
        else
        {
        Serial.println("NO VALIDATION"); 
        }

    }


  if (Reset == "RST")
    {

           for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) 
            {
              mcp.digitalWrite(i,LOW); // Set GPA0 to LOW
            }

        Serial.println("GPA0 is RESET to LOW");

    }

// =========================================================================================

    }  // exit if(Serial.available()>0)

} // exit void loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: do not use Adafruit_MCP23017 library, write your own.

Solution 2: add to Adafruit_MCP23017.c (and declaration to Adafruit_MCP23017.h) a function which will update i2caddr variable. Something like this:

```
void Adafruit_MCP23017::setAddr(uint8_t addr) {
    if (addr < 8) {
      i2caddr = addr;
    }
}
```

this would allow you to change address on the fly.

Comment: Can you please help me with more info about this ? Some links / tutorial / documentation ? Thank you very much for your support !